# Cling as embedded c++ interpreter?

Tags: llvm, cling

I'd like to use Cling as embedded c++ interpreter in my app. At this time it's designed to get console input and provide output. How can it be changed in order to become embedded - to get input stream and provide output stream that can be used in my app?

Answer (score 0):

```
[cling$] .help
...
  .> <filename>     - Redirect command to a given file
  '>' or '1>'       - Redirects the stdout stream only
  '2>'          - Redirects the stderr stream only
  '&>' (or '2>&1')      - Redirects both stdout and stderr
  '>>'          - Appends to the given file
```

This is how one can redirect the streaming of execution results.